# JMeter SSL Manager doesnt work

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jsse

Im trying to use client ssl certificate in JMeter to authenticate on website. The problem is that when i try to import it in SSL Manager, im not getting any message for password, anything. In configuration i've written:

```
user.classpath=/home/m/Downloads/jre-1.7.0_09/usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/
ssl.provider=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
```

I've added `user.classpath` because jsse.jar stands there, but i think its not necessary. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Eh, i had many things to do and i didn't have a time to test it. I've tested my website with funkload and thats why i forgot about that. I will try to try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

To test Client Certificates, use this:

- [Keystore Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration)

Steps are:

1. Create your certificates either with Java keytool utility or through your PKI
2. If created by PKI, import your keys in Java Key Store by converting them to a format acceptable by JKS
3. Then reference the keystore file through the 2 JVM properties :
       -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore
       -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore
4. You use either HTTPClient 3.1 or 4 implementations for HTTP Request

To make JMeter use more than one certificate you need to ensure that:

```
https.use.cached.ssl.context=false
```

is set in jmeter.properties or user.properties

Comment: (4) is unnecessary. The prior steps ensure that *all* JSSE sockets will use the keystore.

Comment: It is necessary for multiple SSL clients

Comment: Thank you, i will check out this. I were trying similar method but maby ive done something wrong.

Comment: Why i cant add them to system.properties? I were similar method before (with this file), its wrong?

Comment: Did you try this ? I will answer your question once I get feedback

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE No, it is not necessary. Step 3 configures the default SSLContext. The number of SSL clients is irrelevant.

Comment: What I meant is: it is when you want to use multiple different client certificates